# Why might we have 3 twin wires in our doorbell chime?

Tags: uk, doorbell

We're currently looking to replace our wired doorbell, but before doing so I wanted to understand the existing wiring - unfortunately I don't!

We have a transformer next to our consumer unit supplying 12V AC to the circuit, and a single push button outside the front door (which only has a single pair coming to it).  Each of these accounts for 1 pair of twin wires arriving into the chime - why might there be a third pair?

[image]

Each of the pairs has one wire commoned together in the wire nut.  From what I can tell, it seems the transformer supply is connected to the T3 terminal, with the other two on 0F.

I'm intending to replace this like-for-like, just with a nicer looking chime, so I could just reconnect everything as-is on the new one, but I'd like to know what this other wire is for!  Does this imply that we might have another push button somewhere?

If I separate out the two non-transformer leads, and try one at a time to figure out which is the actual push button, am I probably better off leaving the other pair disconnected, since we have no idea where it might be going?

Comment: three wire pairs ... 1. power ... 2. front door switch ... 3. back door switch

Comment: Do you have a back door or some sort of intercom system or entry system if in a multi occupancy bldg?

Comment: No, we’re completely detached with no sign of another button anywhere.  Given other things we’ve found in the house, it really wouldn’t surprise me to find the wires are just buried in a wall somewhere...

Comment: If you've got a rear door the wires could be buried by the trim or caulked over.

Comment: We’ve got a conservatory on the back - I wonder if one button was lost when that was built but they never disconnected it in the chime - sounds like the best course of action is to figure out which pair is for the button, which is for the transformer, and leave the 3rd disconnected.

Comment: @jsotola , that’s a good answer for this question and it may help others when accepted, not many other options.+ James if your wires go into the attic you could trace them most of the time they are laying loose until they go down into a wall. If you want to add the other one back it you’ll be most of the way back there.

Comment: @JamesThorpe  If the doorbell works now, don't disconnect anything. We always get questions about how the OP disconnected a wire not being used and now nothing works.

Comment: @JACK I’m planning on replacing the unit with one that isn’t covered in the previous occupants grease (don’t ask), so it’s more a case of not reconnecting things than it is disconnecting them :) Will all be labelled nicely though so if it doesn’t work with a pair disconnected, it can go back as before. And failing all else, the transformer is easy to disconnect and we can just chuck in a wireless one...

Comment: @JamesThorpe Got it .... good luck stay safe.

Answer (score 2):

Three pairs are most likely connected to the three other components in the doorbell system, the transformer, the "front door" pushbutton and the "back door" pushbutton.

The circuit diagram is something like this.

[image]